# How to create an array directory tree based on a string of arrays

Tags: php

In PHP, I don't know how the approach or to create a recursive function to create an array of directory tree.

I am currently provided with this data (array of strings), so i need to do a recursion to create a directory tree. The intention is to create a recursion, so that regardless of the depth of the directory, it will still be able to map an array directory tree

```
array: [
  0 => "root"
  1 => "root/directory1"
  2 => "root/directory1/directory1-1"
  3 => "root/directory2"
  4 => "root/directory2/directory2-1"
  5 => "root/directory3"
  6 => "root/directory3/directory3-1"
  7 => "root/directory3/directory3-1/directory3-1-1"
  8 => "root/directory3/directory3-1/directory3-1-2"
  9 => "root/directory4"
]
```

based on that data, i need to generate something like this:

```
array: [
  0 => array: [
    "id" => 1
    "label" => "root"
    "path" => "root"
    "children" => array: [
        0 => array: [
            "id" => 1
            "label" => "directory1"
            "path" => "root/directory1"
            "children" => array: [
                0 => array: [
                    "id" => 1
                    "label" => "directory1-1"
                    "path" => "root/directory1/directory1-1"
                    "children => []
                ]
            ]
        ]
        1 => array: [
            "id" => 2
            "label" => "directory2"
            "path" => "root/directory2"
            "children" => array: [
                0 => array: [
                    "id" => 1
                    "label" => "directory2-1"
                    "path" => "root/directory1/directory2-1"
                    "children => []
                ]
            ]
        ],
        2 => array: [
            "id" => 3
            "label" => "directory3"
            "path" => "root/directory3"
            "children" => array:1 [
                0 => array: [
                    "id" => 1
                    "label" => "directory3-1"
                    "path" => "root/directory3/directory3-1"
                    "children => array: [
                        0 => array: [
                            "id" => 1
                            "label" => "directory3-1-1"
                            "path" => "root/directory3/directory3-1/directory3-1-1"
                            "children => []
                        ]
                        1 => array: [
                            "id" => 2
                            "label" => "directory3-1-2"
                            "path" => "root/directory3/directory3-1/directory3-1-2"
                            "children => []
                        ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        3 => array: [
            "id" => 4
            "label" => "directory4"
            "path" => "root/directory4"
            "children" => array: []
        ],
    ]
]
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this. Spent several hours trying out different stuff. Thanks alot!